# Microsoft Azure - Could not load the script for the following API...Error 500

Tags: azure

[Cross-post from MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/172e2c6c-aefc-4ccf-87e1-e8cdeb134098/could-not-load-the-script-for-the-following-apierror-500?forum=azuremobile)

All of a sudden I can no longer load the server-side Javascripts for my Mobile Services tables for either of my two Mobile Services, and for any of their tables. I can still access the other table tabs ("Browse", "Columns", etc.), but not "Scripts". When I try to do so, I get the following error:

`Could not load the script for the following API: <Name-of-Table> Error 500".`

I tried logging out and back in in both Safari and Chrome, but got the same. The status of both Mobile Services is "Ready".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this just happens periodically? I can access APIs from both Mobile Services now, with no indication from Microsoft that they needed to fix anything.